# NGINX Reverse Proxy Subdirectory Only

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

My web application has a sub-directory, `192.168.1.8:8088/messages`, that I want to expose to the outside world as `messages.mysite.com`. I've gotten half way there but I seem to be stuck. My requirements are as follows

1. Redirect the site from HTTP to HTTPS.
2. As I cannot edit the links the web application generates, I need to be able to accept requests from the client such as `messages.mysite.com/messages?id=23023`.
3. Do not allow reverse proxy access to the root web application, `192.168.1.8:8088` or to any sub-directory other than `192.168.1.8:8088/messages` and its children.

My current NGINX configuration has some issues.

1. The HTTP to HTTPS redirection only works for the base path, `messages.mysite.com`. If an HTTP request like `http://messages.mysite.com/messages?id=23023` comes in, my server redirects to `http://messages.mysite.com/messages/messages?id=23023` which is incorrect. This is because I have `/messages` in the `return 301` setting, but without it I don't know how else to redirect `messages.mysite.com` to `192.168.1.8:8088/messages`.
2. The HTTPS site allows access to the full web application, `192.168.1.8:8088`, but I only want it to access `192.168.1.8:8088/messages`.

My NGINX site configuration file is below. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
server {
        listen                          80;
        server_name                     messages.mysite.com;
        return 301                      https://$server_name/messages$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen                          443 ssl;
        server_name                     messages.mysite.com;
        set                             $upstream 192.168.1.8:8088;

        ssl_certificate                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/messages.mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key             /etc/letsencrypt/live/messages.mysite.com/privkey.pem;
        include                         /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam                     /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_pass                              http://$upstream;
                proxy_buffering                         off;
                proxy_set_header Host                   $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $scheme;
        }
}
```

Update for clarification:

Examples

```
https://messages.mysite.com => 192.168.1.8:8088/messages
https://messages.mysite.com/messages?id=23023 => 192.168.1.8:8088/messages?id=23023
https://messages.mysite.com/messages/send_message => 192.168.1.8:8088/messages/send_message
https://messages.mysite.com/calendar => 404
https://messages.mysite.com/notmessages=> 404
```

Comment: Please clarify exact example source URL / destination URL pairs in your question in order to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I have updated the question with examples. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want `/` to go to `/messages`, but not `/?id=23023` to go to `/messages?id=23023`? This looks like unnecessary complex setup.

Comment: Because the business requirement are that the base URL be `messages.mysite.com` and not `messages.mysite.com/messages`. Sadly, not my choice. 

As the application server includes a `/messages` path in the links it sends out to the clients, the clients send requests with `/messages` included. I need to remove the `/messages` the clients send as I'm already sending incoming traffic to `192.168.1.8:8088/messages` via the NGINX setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks you are mixing up redirecting reverse proxying.

Redirecting is a server response to tell client to load another URL.

Reverse proxying is telling the server to send the request to another server and return the response back to the client.

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect should always be a simple redirect of the HTTP URL to the corresponding HTTPS URL, without modifications. There is rarely any need to modify the URL path at this step.

Therefore, your redirect block should be:

```
server {
    listen                          80;
    server_name                     messages.example.com;
    return 301                      https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

To reverse proxy requests arriving at `messages.example.com` to `192.168.1.8:8088/messages`, use the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen                          443 ssl;
    server_name                     messages.example.com;

    ssl_certificate                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/messages.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/letsencrypt/live/messages.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include                         /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam                     /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location = / {
        proxy_pass                           http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages;
        proxy_buffering                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    }

    location /messages {
        proxy_pass                           http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages;
        proxy_buffering                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    }
}
```

I removed the `$upstream` variable, because the configuration is easier to read when the `location /` and `proxy_pass` variables are next to each other.

This setup forwards requests as follows:

```
https://messages.example.com/ => http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages
https://messages.example.com/?some=value => http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages?some=value
https://messages.example.com/message => http://192.168.1.8:8088/messagesmessage
```

The `proxy_pass` operation is documented in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: Thank your for taking the time to explain. I was indeed conflating redirection and reverse proxying. I have implemented your change but there is still a problem.  Any incoming request that has `/messages` needs the `/messages` part dropped as I am already pointing there with `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages`. The additional `/messages` points the application server to the wrong place. So if the client asks for `messages.mysite.com/messages/?id=3231`, the application should get `http://192.168.1.8:8088/messages/?id=3231` and not `http://192.168.1.8:8088/messagesmessages?id=3231`.

Comment: I updated the answer with a separate block for the exception you added.

Comment: That seems to be what I need. Thank you for time and patience.